# System.IO.IOException: 'The handle is invalid. : '\\.\Con''

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

I have a WPF NET core app and trying to write file locally.

```
var movies = await GetMovies(_settings.MovieFolderId);
foreach (var movie in movies)
{
      Message = $"Writing locally {movie.Name}";
    
      var meta = Path.Combine(pathToSave, $"{movie.Name}.meta");
      if (!File.Exists(meta))
      {
        await File.WriteAllTextAsync(meta, $"{movie.Id}\r\n{movie.Parents?.FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty}");
      }
}
```

and I got:

[image]

and `meta` value is : `C:\p\bds\Con.Air.A-MVIE.meta`

Why ? It does not happens to all file(s) from that iteration.

Comment: in windows you can't save a file with name `con`. https://superuser.com/q/86999/263134

Comment: To expand on Bizhan’s comment, on Windows, `con` (and `nul` and a few others) can’t appear *anywhere* in a path, and can’t form the filename base without extension either. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file

Comment: There's page which says that ?

Comment: @KonradRudolph not exactly anywhere, you can have `sth.con.txt` but not `con.txt` or `con.sth.txt`

Comment: @SnakeEyes You can google it, to me it's more of an ancient knowledge from 90's

Comment: @Bizhan In your example the filename without extension isn’t `con`, it’s `sth.con`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph the filename is `sth.con` the extension is `txt`, to be more precise your filename cannot start with `con.` or cannot equate `con`

Comment: @Bizhan Yes that’s what I meant, typo.

Comment: use `@"\\?\" + meta`. That prefix disables win32 name canonicalization

Comment: @phuclv That’s a pretty terrible solution, to be honest: it will break *tons* of applications. A better solution is to simply avoid invalid filenames. If necessary, by automatically escaping them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as the comments say "con" is not allowed.
Below is Microsoft Doc extract:

> Do not use the following reserved names for the name of a file:

> CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: +1 for MSDN link, It would be nice to also explain why `Con.Air.A-MVIE.meta` falls into that category. Since the filename is `Con.Air.A-MVIE` not `con`

Comment: The MSDN link goes further to say :
**Also avoid these names followed immediately by an extension; for example, NUL.txt is not recommended**

Comment: @SnakeEyes windows filesystem is not case sensitive, but the reason that it includes `Con.Air.A-MVIE` is as @gkulshrestha mentioned, the reserved names should not be immediately followed by extension (which still doesn't make it final, since neither `Air` nor `A-MVIE` are not extensions, `meta` is)